# Append List to XML

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I am trying to append my list to an XML file.

I have my c# class `PasswordSettings` which contains some properties:

```
public class PasswordSettings {
    public string customerRef { get; set; }
    public string node { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string login { get; set; }
    public string password { get; set; }
    public string fileType { get; set; }
}
```

I have a list of `PasswordSettings` like this:

```
public List<PasswordSettings> Logins = new List<PasswordSettings>();
```

I now add elements to my object and add the object to my list:

```
PasswordSettings settings = new PasswordSettings();

settings.customerRef = "abc";
settings.name = "test";

Logins.add(settings);
```

Now I want to add this list to an XML file so I end up with something like:

```
<PasswordSettings>
    <Logins>
        <customerRef>abc</customerRef>
        <name>test</name>
    </Logins>
</PasswordSettings>
```

And if I want to add another login, it will append to the XML file, i.e. not replace or overwrite anything, so a new `<Logins>`

I have tried multiple methods and I either get null pointers or nothings gets written. I suppose the nullpointer could be because the XML file is empty, but I just want it to add this list as an XML structure.

Comment: in the final xml the root is PasswordSettings and you  have lot of Logins elements?

Comment: yes exactly that

Comment: so you know you have to load the file before adding new element? if file is big its not good..

Comment: Can you post a template of the XML file you are starting with?

Comment: There is nothing in it as It's empty. Called Passwords.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is a solution to create xml or add a new record, so after you could adapt following what you want:

```
        PasswordSettings settings = new PasswordSettings();
        settings.customerRef = "abc";
        settings.name = "test";
        Logins.Add(settings);
        settings = new PasswordSettings();
        settings.customerRef = "def";
        settings.name = "test1";
        Logins.Add(settings);

        foreach (var login in Logins)
        {
            if (!File.Exists(@"e:\Test.xml"))
            {
                XDocument doc =
                    new XDocument(
                        new XElement("PasswordSettings",
                            new XElement("Logins",
                                new XElement("customerRef", login.customerRef),
                                new XElement("name", login.name)
                            )
                        )
                    );

                doc.Save(@"e:\Test.xml");
            }
            else
            {
                XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(@"e:\Test.xml");
                XElement root = doc.Element("PasswordSettings");
                IEnumerable<XElement> rows = root.Descendants("Logins");
                XElement firstRow = rows.First();
                firstRow.AddBeforeSelf(
                    new XElement("Logins",
                        new XElement("customerRef", login.customerRef),
                        new XElement("name", login.name)));
                doc.Save(@"e:\Test.xml");
            }
        }

        }
```

xml output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PasswordSettings>
  <Logins>
    <customerRef>def</customerRef>
    <name>test1</name>
  </Logins>
  <Logins>
    <customerRef>abc</customerRef>
    <name>test</name>
  </Logins>
</PasswordSettings>
```

here i add at the beginning of file, if you want to add at the end of file, just do:

```
                XElement firstRow = rows.Last();
                firstRow.AddAfterSelf(
                    new XElement("Logins",
                        new XElement("customerRef", login.customerRef),
                        new XElement("name", login.name)));
```

output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PasswordSettings>
  <Logins>
    <customerRef>abc</customerRef>
    <name>test</name>
  </Logins>
  <Logins>
    <customerRef>def</customerRef>
    <name>test1</name>
  </Logins>
</PasswordSettings>
```